# K&R exercise 1-8. I can get my code to work correctly

Tags: c, command-line, freebsd, cc

I searched but didn't find a solution.
The program is supposed to count tabs, newlines and spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c,nl,tab,blank;
    tab = 0;
    blank = 0;
    nl = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == '\n');
            nl++;
        if(c == '\t');
            tab++;
        if(c == ' ');
            blank++;
    }

    printf("newline: %d tab: %d blank: %d\n", nl,tab,blank);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on FreeBSD using the <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> to signal EOF, every variable is displayed with the same value. If I type "hello<kbd>blank</kbd> how<kbd>tab</kbd>are<kbd>enter</kbd>you<kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>ctrl-d</kbd>"
it displays newline as 18, tab as 18, blank as 18.

Is my code wrong? Obviously it is, but what's wrong?

Comment: Take the semicolons off the end of your if statements, e.g. `if(c == '\n');` -> `if(c == '\n')`. (Also, not a bug as such, but learn to format your code properly.)

Comment: thanks, my mistake with the formating. @PaulR

Comment: If using gcc or clang, compiling with `-Wall` warning flag would have found this problem

Comment: @M.M will do. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said, problem here is you have semicolons after your if statements. Generally, if statements are wrapped in braces as such:

```
    if(foo) {
        //your code here
    }
```

Try that and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

`if (something);` means literally: *if something, then do nothing*.  the `if` statement syntax makes that putting the semicolon at the end converts it in a null statement to be executed if the condition `something` is true, so if the condition states, nothing is done.  As you increment the three variables after the `if` statements, you'll have them incremented *for each* character you read from the file, and them all with the same value.

## Solution

Just erase the `;` after the condition right parenthesis, as in:

```
if(c == '\n') /* no semicolon here */
        nl++;
```

In a FreeBSD system:

```
$ make pru$$
cc -O -pipe  pru24720.c  -o pru24720
$ pru$$ <pru$$.c
newline: 23 tab: 0 blank: 123
```

Comment: thanks, I have no idea what your make at the end does. I'm just starting with c so I guess ill work up to that. And I'm also beginning to learn unix so a lot of things are confusing but I learning a little a day.

Comment: Well, when I answer a question here, I call always the file `pru$$.c`, which substitutes the `$$` by the pid of the shell, so it gets a different number (and fixed all the shell session).  In this case, the shell pid was `24720`, so that was the name of the file... finally, I executed `pru24720` redirecting it's input from file `pru24720.c` (the source code) to get the number of lines of your sample code, number of tabs and number of blanks.

Comment: Is this a built in unix command or is it something you wrote?

Comment: @clawhammer1234, `make(1)` is a standard unix command, and the shell substitution of the pid with `$$`  is also standard of the bourne shell `sh(1)`  and `bash(1)`. I have only written the `pru24720.c` to illustrate my answer, nothing else.